# How do I POST a POJO via Spring/REST?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I apologize in advance for the length of this post. I hope I can describe this well enough. I am learning REST as I go.

I am attempting to write a service that makes requests of other services via a RESTful API. Spring Boot is being used to provide a lot of the capability behind the scenes.

An example service call will make a `POST` call to another service and pass a POJO. The called service's controller (`@RestController`) defines an endpoint that consumes and produces `application/json`.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this to work. Depending on the things I've tried, I get various types of exceptions.

Below are snippets of the code.

The called service's controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rst/missionPlanning")
public class RouteGeneratorController {

  @Autowired
  private RouteGenerator service;

  @PostMapping(value = "/generateRoute", consumes = "application/json",
      produces = "application/json")
  public ResponseEntity<CommandStatus> generateRoute(@RequestBody Command message) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.generateRoute(message));
  }
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
public class RouteGenerator {
...
  public CommandStatus generateRoute(Command message) {
  ...
  }
}
```

The "client":

```
@Service
public class MissionPlanner {

  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public void planMission() {
    logger.info("MissionPlanner.planMission()");

    Command mpCommand = new Command();
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<Command> entity = new HttpEntity<>(mpCommand);

    ResponseEntity<CommandStatus> response =
        template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute", entity,
            CommandStatus.class);
    CommandStatus statusMsg = response.getBody();
  }
}
```

With the client written as shown above I get the following exception:

```
2019-07-24 10:46:45.601  WARN 13920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml' not supported]
```

Not sure where XML fits in the picture here, except perhaps because the POJO classes were generated via XJC from an XML schema (XSD).

I figured since the called service expects JSON that maybe I need to tell it to use JSON representation. So I tried the following:

```
@Service
public class MissionPlanner {

  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public void planMission() {
    logger.info("MissionPlanner.planMission()");

    Command mpCommand = new Command();
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<Command> entity = new HttpEntity<>(mpCommand, headers);

    ResponseEntity<CommandStatus> response =
        template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute", entity,
            CommandStatus.class);
    CommandStatus statusMsg = response.getBody();
  }
}
```

And got this:

```
2019-07-24 11:07:24.887 ERROR 19384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [collection type; class xyz.BoundedList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xyz.BoundedList` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no default no-arguments constructor found
```

**NOTE**: `xyz.BoundedList` is a type defined by the same schema that defines the message types (`Command`, `CommandStatus`, etc).

OK, so that wasn't the right thing to do.

So, then I tried to just convert the POJO to a JSON string via Jackson. This doesn't really make sense to me to do this, but I'll give it a try any way.

```
@Service
public class MissionPlanner {

  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public void planMission() {
    logger.info("MissionPlanner.planMission()");

    Command mpCommand = new Command();
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = null;

    try {
      json = mapper.writeValueAsString(mpCommand);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      logger.error("Exception", e);
    }

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);

    ResponseEntity<CommandStatus> response =
        template.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/rst/missionPlanning/generateRoute", entity,
            CommandStatus.class);
    CommandStatus statusMsg = response.getBody();
  }
}
```

The exception this time looks very similar (if not the same) as the previous try:

```
2019-07-24 11:16:06.528 ERROR 6096 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [collection type; class xyz.BoundedList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xyz.BoundedList` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no default no-arguments constructor found
```

*What do I need to do to get the POJO object passed to the service?*

**NOTE:**

As an aside, I notice that Spring Boot automatically took care of the proper wiring, conversion (or whatever) for a slightly different call. This was an endpoint I used when I was figuring out how the `@Service`/`@Controller` mechanism worked. It is as follows:

controller:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/data", produces = "application/json")
  public ResponseEntity<AssessmentRequestStatus> data() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.data());
  }
```

service:

```
  public AssessmentRequestStatus data() {
    AssessmentRequestStatus statusMsg = new AssessmentRequestStatus();
    ...
    return statusMsg;
  }
```

This uses `GET` instead of `POST` because it was just testing if I could get a POJO across. When I put in the appropriate "address" in a web browser, the message in JSON form renders. Sweet.

Somehow, the whole Spring/REST mechanism knew the right thing to do to get this to work.

My question is: why doesn't this work for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: RestTemplate tries to figure out how to serialize/deserialize request/response based on the data model. And based on your description the classes might be annotated with XML annotations. You could try to remove these annotations from request and response classes, or you could define which message converters can be used by RestTemplate: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#RestTemplate-java.util.List-

Comment: Yes, the POJO classes do have XML-specific annotations (JAXB-specific might be more accurate), however it seems to work fine in the `GET` example I provided at the end.

Comment: I did a quick look at the link provided by @Yossarian and get the impression that I would need to create an implementation for every message type. If that is the case, that means over 300 of them. If it also involves the supporting types that make up the content of the message types, the number expands to well over 2000.

Comment: What do you mean by message type? If you use json everywhere you need to pass only a single converter into the RestTemplate constructor. I think this one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html

Comment: The "messages" that are sent are defined by an XML schema (XSD). They all subclass an abstract base class to inherit a common structure. The Java classes (the POJOs) are generated from the schema via XJC. Perhaps what you speak of doesn't care. I don't know enough about this to know.

Comment: Modified the code to pass an instance of `org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` to the `RestTemplate`.
Reading the javadocs for this class seems to suggest that it might work. In any case, I ran it again and get a slightly different exception:
-- DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml' not supported]
-- DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

Comment: Probably, I'm misunderstanding the issue. But why do you pass JAXB converter if you want your model to be handled as JSON?

Comment: Could you try passing this class instead? MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Comment: Tried passing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and got an exception very much like the "bounded list" exception described in the original post.

Comment: The nagging question for me is: why does the scenario I describe at the bottom of my original post work just fine with very little code? It "just works".

Comment: Do the generated classes (like BoundedList) define any constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196941/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-yossarian).